# The instance of entity type 'User' cannot be tracked because another instance with the same key value for is already being tracked. Not structural

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, dbcontext

For a project I'm trying to make a certain `User` a `Trainer` of a given `Club`.
For this, I created an entity, `Trainer` which has a one to one with `User`.
The club then has Collections of Users and Trainers.

It all goes fine when adding trainers to the club, and they are added correctly to the database. But once I also add a certain role to the user, it gives me a   `System.InvalidOperationException: The instance of entity type 'User' cannot be tracked because another instance with the same key value for {'Id'} is already being tracked` error.

The weird thing, is that the first time, I send the request, it works, the second time it gives this error. When i restart the debug, and execute the endpoint again, it does work, but then when I upgrade another user, it again gives this error.

#### Club navigation props

```cs
public IReadOnlyCollection<Trainer> Trainers => _trainers;
public IReadOnlyCollection<User> Members => _members;
```

#### User navigation props

```cs
public IReadOnlyCollection<Trainer> Trainers => _trainers;
```

### Trainer navigation props

```cs
public UserId UserId { get; private set; }
public User? User { get; private set; } 
public ICollection<Club> Clubs => _clubs;
```

### Handler to create trainer and add user role

```cs
    public async Task<Result> Handle(AddTrainerToClubCommand command,
        CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        var club = await _clubRepository.FindByIdAsync(command.ClubId, 
            x => x.Include(club => club.Trainers).ThenInclude(t => t.User), cancellationToken: cancellationToken);
        
        if (club is null)
        {
            return Result.NotFound(typeof(Club));
        }
        
        // check if trainer is already trainer in club
        if (club.Trainers.Any(trainer => trainer.UserId.Equals(UserId.Create(command.AddTrainerToClubRequest.UserId))))
        {
            return Result.Failure(ClubErrors.TrainerAlreadyInClub);
        }
        
        var user = await _userRepository.FindByIdAsync(UserId.Create(command.AddTrainerToClubRequest.UserId), cancellationToken: cancellationToken);
        
        if (user is null)
        {
            return Result.NotFound(typeof(User));
        }
        
        var trainer = new Trainer(TrainerId.Create(Guid.NewGuid()), user);
        club.AddTrainer(trainer);
        
        await _trainerRepository.AddAsync(trainer, cancellationToken);
        await _unitOfWork.SaveChangesAsync(cancellationToken);

        return Result.Success();
    }
}
```

### inside of the Trainer constructor

```cs
    public Trainer(TrainerId id,
        User user)
        : base(id)
    {
        UserId = user.Id;
        User = user;
        User.AddRole(Role.ClubTrainer); <-- once I add this line of code, it gives the error
    }
```

EDIT:
I’m using ef-core 8.0.0.

The roles is an custom entity

```cs
public class Role : Enumeration<Role>
{
    public static readonly Role RegisteredUser = new Role(1, "RegisteredUser");
    public static readonly Role DummyRole = new Role(2, "DummyRole");
    public static readonly Role ClubAdmin = new Role(3, "ClubAdmin");
    public static readonly Role ClubOwner = new Role(4, "ClubOwner");
    public static readonly Role ClubTrainer = new Role(5, "ClubTrainer");
    
    public Role(
        int id,
        string name)
        : base(id, name)
    {
    }

    public ICollection<Permission> Permissions { get; set; } = new List<Permission>();
    public ICollection<User> Users { get; set; } = new List<User>();
}
```

the AddRole is nothing more then a Roles.add(role) in the collection of roles in the user entity

Comment: What is `Role.ClubTrainer` and what happens in `User.AddRole`? Also, is this entity-framework or entity-framework-core? (And which version?)

Comment: I edited the post to provide the information you asked for

Comment: EF Core neither has nor needs single-entity "repositories" over its Unit-of-Work, ie DbContext. The problem is caused by this antipattern. The Unit-of-Work already tracks all the entities it loads. If you try to attach an already tracked object you'll get an error.  If you attach an untracked object with the same ID as a tracked one, you get an error. 
 `Add` and `AddAsync` don't insert anything to the database, they *attach* an untracked object in the `Added` state. `SaveChangesAsync` commits **all** pending changes but doesn't clear the real Unit-of-Work, ie DbContext.

Comment: EF Core like other full-featured ORMs aren't database drivers that need abstracting. They try to give the impression of working with in-memory objects or an object database instead of tables and rows. Ideally the application code shouldn't even notice the objects come from a database (doesn't always work). A DbContext isn't a connection that can be kept for long (although connections shouldn't be kept open either). It's a Unit-of-Work meant to capture the changes for a specific use case and then disposed. In web apps this gives you transaction-per-request behavior for free.

Comment: I dont think it has anything to do with the repository pattern. I changed all to do it directly on the dbcontext and no change. I think it has something to do with the garbage disposal after the save changes. Because every first  call that is being made is sucessfull. And every second call of another user im trying to upgrade. Is given this error.